# how to send live data from windows application to webform(asp website)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms, httprequest

I have made a small speech to text recognition win app,and can store the speech(recognised predefined words/letters) into variables.

Now, i want to send these variables to my windows form/website whatever the simplest way possible (may be query string)

But the condition is my webform and winapp both will remain open and the data should be showed - not on a new web window or new browser tab, but on the current opened webform/website i.e. live.(no database in between)

Is this achievable? if yes please help me with some sample code or reference link.

**Note:The webpage can be refreshed,no problem in that but data must show on current opened page only**

Comment: The best way to do this is making API in your website and call them in app.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta any reference/sample code? beginner here.thnks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

Comment: quite lengthy and no involvement of web application there.

Comment: You need to use some queue mechanism where you put data in a queue from winform. And your web application reads data from the queue. The webform should poll the web server every few seconds, the web server will read data from the queue if it's available and send as a response to web form and webform displays it. You can read about Aws SQS, AJAX and MVC.